# What if log file size exceeds my claimed Persistent volume?

Tags: openshift, persistent-volumes

I am working on logging of my application on Persistent Volume.

I am using OpenShift, I created storage(Persistent volume under nas-thin class) and allocated 64Gib to it. I added mount path to this PV for one of my pods where my application is running and generating logs in one of the folder named "logs".
My mount path is "/logs". Hence anything inside this folder will be root for my PVC.

I am appending my logs inside logs folder in a single file.
I tried to read about expanding PV but couldn't understand much.

What would happen if my log file size exceeds  allocated PV size(which is 64Gib)?

Comment: Depending on your application. Such as, stopped with IO error due to not writing the logs any more, suspended the current process until writing logs again.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the persistent storage actually being used by the cluster. Some persistent volume providers will let you write more data than you actually defined. So you'll have to test how your storage and your application actually behave on your particular cluster.

That being said, it is generally **a bad idea to have container workload log to a persistent volume**. I would strongly recommend [to log to STDOUT](https://12factor.net/logs) and then use an external logging system to manage your logs instead of writing to a file.

How will you deal with multiple replicas of your application running? Do you really want to go into each container to get the log files? How will you correlate logs between different replicas?

Applications running on OpenShift / Kubernetes should not manage their logs in files but write to STDOUT.